# Visible fireflies using object's Texture Coordinate

Tags: mesh, normals, procedural, texture-coordinates

Making a simple procedural metal shader using a `Noise Texture` node linked to a `Normal Map` effect from the object's Texture Coordinate, **I've come across this particular issue:**

[image: texture coordinate fireflies]

When I change the `Normal Map` value there's a very visible firefly that appears in the mesh, affecting the texture in some particular areas.

My first thought at this was that I had a `Face Orientation` or `Duplicated Vertex` issue. But to my surprise, all the Face/Vertex Normals seems good, and there were no duplicated vertexes.

**See mesh analysis:**

[image: mesh analysis]

**My node setup:**

[image]

At this point, I knew that this issue went far beyond my acknowledgments, and this is what I've got so far.

**Objective:**

- Find the property or the mistake I've made that brings this particular issue.
- Notice if this is a `Texture Coordinate` bug from Blender with no troubleshooting so far.

**Things I've noted:**

- When the `Normal Map` value is `0` this issue disappears.
- All mesh normals are facing their correct direction.
- There's no duplicated vertex or faces.

**Rules:**

- This shader must be procedural for further use in different objects.
- Texture coordinate must be plugged in `Object` input.
- No `UV maps` dependency or mesh wrapping.

**Extra points for:**

- An alternative solution to make this procedural shader with no `UV map` or not depending on the object's `Texture Coordinate`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit: here's the original `.blend` file [image]**

Comment: I may miss something that I don't understand but I don't see any reason to use a Normal Map node if you don't plug any normal map image into it?

Comment: What I want to achieve with this is more like a superficial stain effect than depth. That's why I choose the Normal Map node over Bump. I might be wrong on this, I'm not an expert in the shading vectors field.

Comment: You can have a superficial effect with bumps, it's all a question of settings, but I'm trying to understand your setup, Normal Map needs normal map image to work properly